# Were there any extra objects in the latest Falcon 9 launch?

Tags: launch, debris, falcon-9

The previous launch of the Falcon 9 included [a number of mysterious objects](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2377/25). Has there been any indication that the recent SES launch produced similar objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the latest JSPOC reports, there were only 2 objects in the launch, one which is SES, and another which looks like a booster. As it's been almost a week, it looks like in fact this launch did not include any extra objects.

Source is [Celestrak](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/tle-new.txt), viewed Dec 10 2013. Here's the current TLE's for launch 71 (SES/Falcon 9). Only the two objects there.

```
2013-071A               
1 39460U 13071A   13343.67928412 -.00000371  00000-0  00000+0 0   102
2 39460   1.2047 242.7304 3426221 179.1602  40.9644  0.53381995    40
2013-071B               
1 39461U 13071B   13343.10381580  .00000511  00000-0  11828-1 0    51
2 39461  20.4397 242.1309 8535840 180.6297 176.0625  0.87328304    54
```